# adldap2 integration with laravel 5.3 binding to Auth driver

Tags: laravel-5.3, adldap

Ok, so there is some documentation on this, which I've followed (https://github.com/Adldap2/Adldap2-Laravel), but I cannot seem to get this working. I'm also using laravel 5.3 so I don't know if that has something to do with it. And please bear with me as I'm new to laravel.

I cannot authenticate using the Auth::attempt($creds) method.

I can, however authenticate with Adldap::user()->attempt($user,$pass)

I want to use the Auth facade so I can verify logins and such. If there is another way to do it without using Auth I'm all ears.

I also want to bind to the User model once that user has logged in, but I haven't gotten far enough to see if that works.

I've been working on this for a few days and I think it's time I reach out. Please help!

Here's what I'm working with...

adldap.php:

```
'auto_connect' => false,
```

adldap_auth.php:

```
'bind_user_to_model' => env('ADLDAP_BIND_USER_TO_MODEL', true)
```

auth.php:

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'adldap',
        'model' => App\Models\User::class,
    ],

    // 'users' => [
    //     'driver' => 'database',
    //     'table' => 'users',
    // ],
],
```

app.php:

```
'aliases' => [
    'Adldap' => Adldap\Laravel\Facades\Adldap::class,
]

'providers' => [

    Adldap\Laravel\AdldapServiceProvider::class,
]
```

controller:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    public function login()
    {
        $input = Input::all();
        if(Auth::attempt([$input['username'],$input['password']])
        {
            return 'Authenticated';
        }
    }
}
```

User model:

```
namespace App\Models;

use Adldap\Laravel\Traits\AdldapUserModelTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract
{
    use Authenticatable, AdldapUserModelTrait;
    use Authenticatable, AdldapUserModelTrait;

}
```

Comment: Any news on this? I'm looking for some help related to your question